# JQgrid column sort not working when clicked for the first time? when clicked again i.e, second time it is working fine?

Tags: jqgrid

There are 4 columns in my jqgrid all other columns sort working fine for first click. But for last column it is not working .I need to click 2 times on header of the column then it is working fine.

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without more information...